# How can I mention a user via JDA-discord?

Tags: java, events, discord-jda

I want to mention the user, as I showed in this picture, I don't understand how to do it, I had attempts I tried to do:

`event.getChannel().send Message("@" + event.getMember().getNickname()).queue();`

or

`event.getChannel().send Message("@everyone").queue();`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord mentions are done using IDs. A user mention is formatted as `<@{user_id}>`. In your message, this would be done this way:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage("<@" + event.getMember().getId() + ">").queue()
```

However, you can also just use the existing method on members:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getMember().getAsMention()).queue()
```

If you only have an id, you can also use [`UserSnowflake`](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/UserSnowflake.html)

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage(UserSnowflake.fromId(id).getAsMention()).queue()
```